# Add up Ansible variable in Jinja2 template

Tags: ansible, jinja2, ansible-template

I have this vars file:

```
addvlan:
 - vlan: pruebavlan
   address: 192.168.10.0
   mask: 25
   gateway: ????
   tag: 1917
```

And I have this JSON which use the vars of above vars:

```
  "address": "{{address}}",
  "mask": {{mask}},
  "gateway": "{{gateway}}",
  "tag": "{{tag}}",
```

I need that the gateway will be always the next IP of the address. For example, in the above case, could be 192.168.10.1

Do you know if it's possible or any way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [`ipaddr` filter](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_filters_ipaddr.html):

```
gateway: "{{ network_address | ipaddr('1') | ipaddr('address') }}"
```

Comment: I got error:  'address' is undefined". I forgot to say that my vars are defined into a list.. Is it possible that this is the error?

Answer (score 1):

Solution without `ipaddr` filter:

```
{{ gateway.split('.')[:3] | join('.') + '.' + (gateway.split('.')[3] | int + 1) | string }}
```

But you **can't** do this:

```
addvlan:
 - vlan: pruebavlan
   address: 192.168.10.0
   mask: 25
   gateway: "{{ << address manipulations here >> }}"
   tag: 1917
```

This will give you recursion error, because you try to define keys of `addvlan.vlan` referencing other keys from same dict.
Do manipulations in your JSON template instead:

```
  ...
  "address": "{{ address }}",
  "mask": "{{ mask }}",
  "gateway": "{{ address.split('.')[:3] | join('.') + '.' + (address.split('.')[3] | int + 1) | string }}",
  "tag": "{{ tag }}",
  ...
```

Comment: I got: 'gateway' is undefined". I forgot to say that my vars are defined into a list.. Is it possible that this is the error?

Comment: Replace `gateway` with appropriate variable name for you setup

Comment: Yes, i did it, i used "listname.gateway" but i got this error: `recursive loop detected in template string: {{ addvlan.gateway.split('.')[:3] | join('.') + '.' + (addvlan.gateway.split('.')[3] | int + 1) | string }}"`

Comment: @hectormarina in Ansible/Jinja you can't define variable based on itself. So `gateway: "{{ gateway + 'zzzz' }}"` gives you a recursion. Change to `z_gateway: "{{ gateway + 'zzzz' }}"` to fix this.

Comment: I change like you said me:

`z_gateway: "{{ addvlan.gateway.split('.')[:3] | join('.') + '.' + (addvlan.gateway.split('.')[3] | int + 1) | string }}"` and i got the same error...

Comment: I update the OP with correct vars setup. Take a look,